# Having the same IAP product ID for multiple apps

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, cross-platform, app-store-connect

My company has a live iPad app running and after deciding not to make it universal , i have to develop an iPhone version , which will be sold as a different product(new app) under the same iTunesConnect account. 
Same non-consumable in-app products will be available for purchase on the iPhone app.

Can I use the same product identifiers(for example: "1207") for both managed in-app products? If so, is there a way to share the existing IAP table(or import) without having to manually re-enter thousands of product details in the in-app table of the new app? I read a little about Apple's Application Loader but I reckon it might involve suicidal behavior and all sorts of nerve ticks.

Just to make it clear - after purchasing from one app, the product will be available from both apps for the same user. The server side can take care of preventing re-purchasing a product the user already owns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it's impossible. The product ID is related to one app only. The only thing you might do (And I don't know it's by the rules), is manage this purchases on your server, and when the user purchase the product on one app, the other app can retrieve this purchase using your server.